# Is there a way to list all sheets on a google spreadsheet using native functions?

Tags: google-sheets

I create many dashboards on Google Spreadsheet, which are basically a spreadsheet containing a bunch of sheets with all sort of different data. Some of these spreadsheets can have up to 30 sheets or more.

I want a way to list the name of all sheets in a spreadsheet on a column using native functions.

I know this could be easily done with a custom function. However this would bring some complications regarding the workflow in my company.

Is there a way to accomplish that without using custom functions?

Thank You very much!

Comment: Unrelated to the question: Someone has suggested changing the word "spreadsheet" for "workbook". I´m not a native speaker, so I don´t really know the correct from. As I understand, workbook is for Excel and spreadsheet is for googlespreadsheet. I´m wrong?

Answer (score -1):

This works in Excel, so if you are able to export your workbook and save it as an Excel file rather than Google Doc this will work.

1. Go to your "Name Manager"
2. Create a 'New' name and call it "Sheets"
3. Insert this formula into the 'Refers to' box `=TRANSPOSE(GET.WORKBOOK(1))&T(NOW())`
4. Now insert this formula where you want the list of Sheet names `=IFERROR(INDEX(MID(Sheets,FIND("]",Sheets)+1,255),ROW(A1),1),"")`
5. Drag the formula down so A1 progresses (A1 represents the sheet number that you are getting the name of).

[Source of solution](http://www.ashishmathur.com/generate-a-list-of-all-tabs-names-without-using-vba/)